# Rails devse - sign_in wrong number of arguments given 7, expected 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Creating an API for my app using devise. Just trying to sign in a user (Officer), the devise sign_in method is throwing an error. For reference, Officers is a table with 7 columns, so I imagine that has something to do with the error I am getting. If anyone has any insight, that'd be greatly appreciated.

```
user = Officer.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:email].downcase)
      if user == nil
        render plain: "Email has not been registered", status: 422
      elsif user.department == nil || user.department.expiration.past?
        render plain: "Expired."
      elsif user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
        if user.authentication_token == nil
            user.authentication_token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
            user.save!
        end
        sign_in(user)
```

Error at line:

```
            sign_in(user)
```

I have also tried:

```
            sign_in(user, scope: :officer)
```

Error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 2)
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sign_in](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FSignInOut:sign_in) method with scope and then resource

```
sign_in :officer, @user
```